# The component sc-global has been created dynamically warning

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

using styled components' `createGlobalStyle` as a workaround an issue i've had in my project, whereby I only want the `background-color` of `.application` to be white when the following component is rendered. The below implementation gives the perfect outcome however I get a warning in the console saying:

"The component sc-global-hEInDv has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component."

Here is the code:

```
  const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    .application {
      background-color: white;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div className={classNames("caseview", className)}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Helmet>
        <title>{caseName}</title>
      </Helmet>
      {caseview.panelLinks.hasItems && (
        <CaseViewDetailPanels caseview={caseview} />
      )}
      <Row>
        <Column size={hasTaskGroup ? 9 : 12}>
          {caseview.introtext && <FormattedText text={caseview.introtext} />}
        </Column>
        {hasTaskGroup && (
          <Column
            as={TaskGroupPanels}
            size={3}
            taskGroupPanels={caseview.taskGroupCollection}
          />
        )}
      </Row>

      <FormRoute model={caseview} />
    </div>
  );
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `styled-component` inside your functional component. If you move it outside the component, this warning will go away.

Move the below styled component, outside.

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  .application {
    background-color: white;
  }
`;
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. One thing I don't understand is that if I then refresh the page, the white bg-color no longer exists, despite the fact the component is clearly still rendered?

Comment: the white background is being applied to the `application` class.  If you want to apply to the whole website, try making it `body`. Like this `body {background-color: white;}`